# How to make clickable images in homepage

Tags: javascript, blogger

Make images Postings homepage clickable
[image: http://i.imgur.com/5C1RmqP.png]

Code I tried :

```
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
var div = document.getElementById(pID);
var imgtag = "";
var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
var summ = summary_noimg;

if(img.length>=1) {
    imgtag = '<div id="thumbnail"><div class="thumbnail"><img    src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></div></div></span>';
    summ = summary_img;
 }
```

Comment: You need to provide some more details.  Perhaps a working jsfiddle or your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

ok prefer

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){
    if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)
    
{
        var s = strx.split("<");
        for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
            if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){
                s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length);
            
}
        
}
       
 strx =  s.join("");
    
}
    
chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2;
    while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++;
    strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1);
    return strx+' ';
}


function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var summ = summary_noimg;




if(img.length>=1) {
 imgtag = '<div id="thumbnail"><div class="thumbnail"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></div></div></span>';

        summ = summary_img;
   
 }

    
var summary = imgtag + '<p>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</p>';
    
div.innerHTML = summary;



}

//]]>
</script>
```